# Getting null value while toggling forms (selecting via DOM) in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, ajax, ejs

I have a simple like and unlike button which shall toggle upon clicking like and unlike respectively in both cases.(sending AJAX calls on clicking each button)

**My Index.html**

```
<%if(video.LikedUsers.some(user=>{return(user.Username===currentUser.Username)})){%>
    <!--Unlike Form-->
            <form id="UnlikeButtonForm" action="/video/<%=video._id%>/unlike?_method=PUT" method="POST"
                style="display: inline;">
                <button id="UnlikeButton">Unlike</button>
            </form>
            <%}else{%>
            <!--Like Form-->
            <form id="LikeButtonForm" action="/video/<%=video._id%>/like?_method=PUT" method="POST"
                style="display: inline;">
                <button id="LikeButton">Like</button>
            </form>
            <%}%>
```

**My Script Containing AJAX Calls**

```
<script>
        var LikeForm = document.querySelector("#LikeButtonForm");
        var UnlikeForm = document.querySelector("#UnlikeButtonForm");
        $("#LikeButtonForm").submit((event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: LikeForm.action,
                success: function () {
                    //console.log(document.getElementById("UnlikeButtonForm")); Shows null
                    LikeForm.style.display="none"; //Like Button is succesfully hidden
                    //UnlikeForm.style.display="inline"; //Throws error
                }
            });
        });
        //Similar script for unlike button 
    </script>
```

How can I fix this issue and toggle forms? **Note, backend works fine**.

Comment: With the code as it is now, you need to reload the page after liking or unliking. It won't magically turn the like button into an unlike button. If you want to handle it without the reload, you could replace it client-side, or - what seems to be the thing you are already trying to do - you could conditionally set the `style="display: none;"` attribute instead of conditionally including the elements.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do, but  UnlikeForm is null in success: callback. So any change in property throws an error and it doesn't change. (Like button successfully disappears tho)

Comment: No right after declaration it doesn't return null, only in success callback.

Comment: I have trouble believing that, because it should not be in the DOM at that point (according to the EJS it can never be in the DOM at the same time as the like form!)

Comment: As I said before, you should probably not conditionally include them but always include both, and instead just put a `style="display: none;"` in an EJS conditional (for both of them, with opposite conditions). You can store your check into a variable before, to avoid repeating it.

Comment: Thanks I Got what you are trying to say, will improve. :)